# How to get rid of spacing between cells of a UITableView on tvOS?

Tags: swift, uitableview, interface-builder, tvos

I am trying to build a tvOS app that has a list of channels on the left side of the screen.
I'm using a UITableView for that. It is anchored at the top, left and bottom of the screen and has a fixed width.
I am trying to make all cells touch each other, without any spacing in between, but I can't figure out how.

On this [image: screenshot] you can see the current result, I have set the background color of the tableview to be blue, the separator color to be red solid line, and the background of my cells to be green.
And we can see there are a few pixels between each cell since we can see the blue color. I'm trying to make it invisible by having the cells touching each other, but couldn't find any property that does that as I have set pretty much all insets, margins, headers and footers heights to 0.

Comment: Show the code you have used to create this.

Comment: use a collection view

Comment: Did you get any answer?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a collectionView - By doing so you can specify the spacing on the collectionView's layout or via the delegate methods. The [UICollectionView Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) may be useful too if you take this approach. Using a collectionView will make your UI more versatile.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```